# Mapbox IOS example "Annotation views" not displaying Custom UIView

Tags: ios, mapbox

I am new to Mapbox and I am trying to learn how to work with Custom Annotated Views. I created a new xcode project (using xcode 11.5, IOS 13.5 and Storyboard option), installed the pods, and setup the access tokens following the installation guide: https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/

I then copied and pasted the code from the Annotation example: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/annotation-views/ into ViewController.swift

When I run the code I get this on the simulator:
[ActualFunctionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOvMz.png)

But I want: [ExpectedFunctionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkePa.png)

After adding print statements, it appears that .layoutSubviews() is never being called within the created CustomAnnotationView's. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

ViewController.swift

```
import Mapbox
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print("{ERFORMED")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.darkStyleURL
        mapView.tintColor = .lightGray
        mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 66)
        mapView.zoomLevel = 2

        mapView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Specify coordinates for our annotations.
        let coordinates = [
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 33),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 66),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 99)
        ]

        // Fill an array with point annotations and add it to the map.
        var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()
        for coordinate in coordinates {
            let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
            point.coordinate = coordinate
            point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
            pointAnnotations.append(point)
        }

        mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        // This example is only concerned with point annotations.
        guard annotation is MGLPointAnnotation else {
            return nil
        }

        // Use the point annotation’s longitude value (as a string) as the reuse identifier for its view.
        let reuseIdentifier = "\(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"

        // For better performance, always try to reuse existing annotations.
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // If there’s no reusable annotation view available, initialize a new one.
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            annotationView!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

            // Set the annotation view’s background color to a value determined by its longitude.
            let hue = CGFloat(annotation.coordinate.longitude) / 100
            annotationView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        }

        return annotationView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class CustomAnnotationView: MGLAnnotationView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        print("LAYOUT SUBVIEWS")
        // Use CALayer’s corner radius to turn this view into a circle.
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Animate the border width in/out, creating an iris effect.
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
        animation.duration = 0.1
        layer.borderWidth = selected ? bounds.width / 4 : 2
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "borderWidth")
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

SceneDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

//        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
//
//            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
//
//            let annotated = Annotation_vc()
//            let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: annotated)
//
//            window.rootViewController = navigation
//
//            self.window = window
//            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
//        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

Xcode setup:

[Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNLH1.png)
[Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3J8Q.png)

[info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK2zS.png)
[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YItT1.png)

Comment: Can you paste your own code here? I’ve used that example previously without problem.

Comment: Okay just updated

Comment: Can confirm your result and can't see why. I've reached out to Mapbox and will let you know if/when they respond.

Comment: After more work I found that it works if you add the annotations after the map has completely loaded. I attached a link to my solution process in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Annotation views should be added after the map has completely loaded
See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/16492 for more details

Comment: This is correct. mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations) needs to be added either in didFinishLoadingMap or didFinishLoadingStyle.